# HTML file input: load already existing filename

Tags: html, sql-server, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm developing a simple Spring web application to manage documents in PDF format, which should be able to perform the usual operations: list them, add a new one, delete and update. These operations go to a MS SQL Server db (the documents table has a VARBINARY(MAX) field to store the document's bytes). The problem arrives when updating a (previously added) file.
Adding the file is easy. The simplied form in the JSP is like this one:

```
<form:form method="post" action="AddDoc" commandName="document" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table id="documentTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Choose file:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><input type="file" name="file" path="file" size="40" value="${document.file}"></p>
                        <p><sf:errors path="file" class="error"/></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p class="submit"><input id="submitForm" type="submit" name="commit" value="Go"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
        </form:form>
```

As you see the form sends a Document object when submitted, which is validated by the controller and inserted into the database. This Document object stores the document's bytes into a MultipartFile before insertion.
Now I want to update this Document object, so the JSP page is the same one as for adding, with the difference that the already existing Document has to be loaded from DB prior to show the page. The form is now populated with the Document info, except the input file field, which I don't know why doesn't get populated (while you can see that `value="${document.file}"`). The problem is that the user might not need to update the file itself, only the other associated attributes that appear on the form, but when it is submitted all fields are properly encapsulated within Document object, except for the file which is empty and causes validation to fail.
I would like to be able to populate the file input field when the update document JSP page is loaded, so the info can be sent again if the user submits the form without changing this field.

I've thought about other solutions, like modifying the validator to accept an empty file field and then getting the info again from DB or session, but this doesn't look neat.

What do you think would be a good approach?

Comment: For security reasons, file upload fields give the user a browse button rather than letting you set the file. Otherwise, malicious developers would always be putting file upload boxes with pre-chosen files in every form and making them invisible with CSS to steal your files.

Comment: I had read something about that, but I hoped there was another simple way of doing this. I would like to avoid code "patches" in the validator or using the session to get the file again. Can anyone tell me which approach do you follow to solve this without too much trouble?

Comment: If its an intranet I'd just store the file on a network share so the user can edit it via the windows filesystem, and in the database would only be a reference to it.  If this is actually on the web, good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but the file itself must be in the database. The path to it is not valid (prone to error if either the path or the doc name changes). Anyway, I finally decided to change a bit the updateDoc form so it gets in a different text field the file name. If the user wants to update the file he is forced to select it again. The controller needs then to check if a new file is being passed or not. Despite not being as simple and neater as I wanted, it does the job.